# How save composite Class

Tags: java, spring, jpa

i have this class, i want to persist this class, but just i get errors.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Participant")
public class Participant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
    User user;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="meet_id")
    Meet meet;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "rol")
    Rol rol;
}
```

When i try save, i get this error:

```
2019-05-20 22:03:29.637 ERROR 17416 --- [nio-8080-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exceptio
n [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.model.User; nested exceptio
n is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.model.User] with root cause

org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.example.demo.model.User
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:765) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar!/:5.0.12.Final]
```

how resolver my problem?

in my service i make this

```
public class MeetServiceImpl {
@Autowired
MeetRepository meetRepository;

@Autowired
UserRepository userRepository;

@Autowired
ParticipantRepository participantRepository;

static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MeetServiceImpl.class.getName());

public Meet createMeet(Long idUser, Meet meet) {
    Meet currentMeet = meetRepository.findByName(meet.getName());
    User user = userRepository.findById(idUser);
    Participant participant = new Participant();

        participant.setRol(Rol.OWNER);
        Meet meet1 = new Meet();
        meet1.setName("nuevo");
        meet1.setState(State.start);

        participant.setMeet(meet1);
        participant.setUser(user);
        participantRepository.save(participant);
        return meetRepository.save(meet);
}
```

I do not understand what the problem is, what I am doing wrong, this seems to have no logic

EXTRA: this is model, 
Below I show the model about the classes I use

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Meet")
public class Meet implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(unique = true, name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "state")
    private State state;
```

and class Meet

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "User")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(unique = true, name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "life")
    Life life;
```

when i comment the id's

//@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

i get this error

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Comment: Could you post the entire service method?

Comment: @MarcoR. i edited my question

Comment: @Transactionalpublic class MeetServiceImpl {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have make double insertion on the object Meet :

```
participantRepository.save(participant);
return meetRepository.save(meet);
```

The problems are : 
 1-The first line (1) save participant and the meet, because you have write in the 
 particpant class :

```
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumn(name="meet_id")
 Meet meet;
```

so any time you save a particpant which is linked to a meet, the meet is save 
 automatically

2-when you comment this line : //@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
the id is not generated so we have two meet which in the insertion statemnt generate by jpa with the id 0.so the database says : Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: after this line : participantRepository.save(participant); you do participant.getMeet();

Answer (score 0):

Your creation method is not does not seem to be transactional. Could you Add @Transactional on top your class or method.

Answer (score 0):

if your using the Spring JPA with Entity Manager you can add the   @Transactional on top of service layer.

```
 @Transactional
    public class MeetServiceImpl {
```